# Как в Jquery взять из input, прочитать файл и по regex вернуть в select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Прошу помощи, в jquery совсем плох пока.

Есть `<input id="cartag" type="text" name="car">`
Если он не пустой - в нем имя файла, нужно взять данное имя , распарить текстовый файл, который находиться локально  в ./tmp, небольшой по регулярному выражению - выбрать строки содержащие "SchemeMap=" и результат вернуть в form в виде списка для выбора select.

Файл находиться на сервере, там же где и сама форма input.

Не на компьютере пользователя!

Все в онлайне без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Имя файла где? На компьютере пользователя?

Comment: Да локальный файл в директории ./tmp

Comment: Скоректировал вопрос. Файл не на машине пользователя, а на машине где находиться сама форма и скрипт.

Comment: $.ajax и вперёд. Придётся что-то писать на сервере, либо тащить весь файл на клиент.